# How to do searching in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, listitem, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to implement a dictionary in my app.For that I'm fetching an api response which contains the data for dictionary.
The api response will be based on the input given by user.If I type letter `a` then corresponding result will be produced.But on further typing of full word ,say `adhaar` then what I'm expecting is to render only that purtcular item.But in my case whatever I type in the search field the result will be same even after the full word is typed.Also I'm not getting the result of word which I'm typing. [I'm following this doc](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-react-native-flatlist-with-realtime-searching-ability-81ad100f6699)
Please help me to figure out my mistake.What wrong I'm doing?Please help.Following is my code

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data:[]
    };
    this.arrayholder = [];
  }
searchFilterFunction = text =>{
  this.setState({ text });
  console.log(this.state.text);
    fetch('xxxxxx', {
         method:'POST',
         headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json'
         },
         body:JSON.stringify({
           s:text,
           loading:false
         })
     }).then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseData) => {

          this.setState({
              data:responseData.data
          })

          this.arrayholder = responseData.data

     })
     .catch(error => {
     this.setState({ error, loading: false });
   });
   const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(item => {
    const itemData = `${item.post_title}`;
     const textData = text;
     return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
     this.setState({ data: newData });
  });

   }
<Container>
     <Header>
         <Item>
           <Input placeholder="Search"
           onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction({text})}
           />
         </Item>
       </Header>
    ...
     ...
   <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
       <FlatList
       data={this.state.data}
       renderItem={({ item }) => (
       <Text>{item.post_title}</Text>
       )}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
       />
       </List>
  <Container>
```

This is how the output screen will be https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXhTb.png

Any help is appreciated.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a scope issue. You have code executing in an asynchronous and code executing after this depending on the asynchronous result. This isn't going to work for you.

There are a few issues in the searchFilter function.

When you are creating the `newData` the setState is written in the filter after the return statement. It will never get called so you are never updating your state.

You're also, what seems to be unnecessary, calling setState multiple times. I think you only need to call it twice. Once when the data has been downloaded and once when the data fails to download.

Here is an updated `searchFilterFunction`, this should give you some ideas on how you could fix your code.

```
searchFilterFunction = text =>{
  console.log(text);
    fetch(
      ...
    )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {

      const filteredData = responseData.data.filter(item => {
        const itemData = `${item.post_title}`;
        const textData = text;
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });

      this.setState({
          data: filteredData, 
          text
      });
    })
     .catch(error => {
     this.setState({ error, loading: false, text });
   });
}
```

- I have removed the setState for text at the start, are you needing to
  set it here as it will force a re-render.
- In the `.then((responseData) => ... )` I have updated it so that you perform the filter straight away on the `responseData.data`, then save the `filteredData` and the `text` to state.
- I removed the setting of `this.arrayholder` I don't think you really require it unless you are using it elsewhere.

In your FlatList I would add the`extraData` prop

> A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it
>   implements PureComponent)

```
<FlatList
  ...
  extraData={this.state}
  ...
>
```

Hopefully that should be enough for your to fix your code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I've tried your method but rendering is not working.Can't find any search results :(

Comment: Are you getting the correct search text into the `searchFilterFunction`? Have you tried logging out the responseData to see if you are getting a response from the server? If you are, have you are getting a response, have you tried logging out the filteredData to see if you are getting any matches there?

Comment: I tried `console.log(this.state.data)` within `render` but I'm getting an empty array. Also I tried `console.log(itemData)` the output was same as before not returning matched item.

Comment: Actually `filteredData` is not there is it is `data` ?

Comment: The steps to fixing this is quite simple. You need to know if you are passing the correct search text to the `searchFilterFunction`. Then you need to check that the responseData is what you expect it to be for the fetch call. Then you need to filter that response so it matches the search text string. If you aren’t going to check those then I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Yeah I tried both.The `searchFilterFunction` produces the expected result.I tried to console the filtered result.It is perfect.

Comment: The actual problem I'm facing is can't perform this `this.setState({data: data})`. After I tried to render `this.state.data` within `FlatList` I'm getting error that `cannot read property data of null`.

Comment: Beacuse I will get value within `data` only after performing the filter function right?So calling the fetch the state will be null initially. Is that can be the problem?

Comment: I just fixed a typo in my code. Obviously the filter should be ` const filteredData = ...` and not `const data = ...`

Comment: Yes , now one  problem is resolved searching takes place fine.But only for first word.if I type any words starting with alphabet `B` then no result will render.But I checked with `Postman` to confirm whether result is coming.It is getting there without any problem.But not working in my code

Comment: Change `return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;` to be something like `return itemData.includes(textData);` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp